# mvc4 upload file I can not invoking MY action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, image-uploading, actionresult

I made an action and using Html.BeginForm to upload image file
my controller name is **ImagesTaple**
and it is like that:

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using bootstrab1.Models;

namespace bootstrab1.Controllers
{
    public class ImagesTableController : Controller
    {
        private SpaDbEntities db = new SpaDbEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Images/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.C_Images.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadImg(HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            if (image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var FileFame = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), FileFame);
                image.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        //
        // GET: /Images/Details/

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            C_Images c_images = db.C_Images.Find(id);
            if (c_images == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(c_images);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Images/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Images/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(C_Images c_images)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.C_Images.Add(c_images);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(c_images);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Images/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            C_Images c_images = db.C_Images.Find(id);
            if (c_images == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(c_images);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Images/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(C_Images c_images)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(c_images).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(c_images);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Images/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            C_Images c_images = db.C_Images.Find(id);
            if (c_images == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(c_images);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Images/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            C_Images c_images = db.C_Images.Find(id);
            db.C_Images.Remove(c_images);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

my BeginForm  is like that

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImg","ImagesTaple", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <table>
<tr>
    <td>file : </td>
    <td><input type="file" name="File" id="file" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><input type="submit" name="submet" value="upload" /></td>
</tr>
  </table>  

}
```

and my action is

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadImg(HttpPostedFileBase image)
        {
            if (image.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var FileFame = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), FileFame);
                image.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
```

now when i press my submet button
i get this error mesage

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /ImagesTaple/UploadImg

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0
```

what is wrong in my code plz
thanx for your help

Comment: can you show all your controller?

Comment: misspelling on ImagesTaple should be ImagesTable

Comment: please  kindly add it as an answer so I can mark it as a correct answer

Comment: also your parameter image is going to be null, try in your action 
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadImg()
        {
            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase _file = Request.Files[file];
            }
.......
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just a misspelling, change ImagesTaple to ImagesTable